# AJAX populated filter breaks when Views Dependant Filter module added

Tags: ajax, views

I have a view with two exposed filters and I want to make the second filter dependant on the first in 2 ways

1. A user has to select an option from the first filter before the second is available to use. Achieved using [Views Dependant Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters)
2. The options within the second filter are dynamically updated so only combinations that will return results are presented. Achieved following this [Views AJAX Dynamic Dependent Exposed Filters](http://bouteillenicolas.com/expertise-drupal/views-ajax-dynamic-dependent-exposed-filters) tutorial and creating a custom module.

I have an [example of this view](http://eiado.prevision.com.au/supplementary-reports/annotated-bibliography) available on this development server.

Select an option from filter one and the second filter becomes available and it's options are updated as expected.

The problem occurs when you select a second different option from the first filter. The AJAX does not fire and the second filter options are not updated.

Code for updating filter two with AJAX is below, but I believe the problem lies on the client side.

I appreciate your suggestions.

```
function dependant_keyword_filter_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-annotated-bibliography-page') {

        $form['#after_build'][] = '_sort_alphabetically';

        if(!empty($form_state['values'])) {
            $form_state['input'] = array_merge($form_state['input'], $form_state['values']);
        }

        $selectedCommodity = $form_state['input']['field_commodity_tid'];
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#options'] = _get_associative_array_from_view(
            'annotated_bibliography_dependant_keywords', // view id
            'default', // view display id
            'taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_keywords_tid', // key field id
            'taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_keywords_name',
            $selectedCommodity // term id of the selected shape
            );
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => '_update_keywords_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'keywords_wrapper',
            );
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax']['progress']['type'] = 'throbber';
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax']['progress']['message'] = 'Updating keywords';
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#prefix'] = '<div id="keywords_wrapper">';
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }
}

function _sort_alphabetically($form, $form_state) {
        foreach ($form_state['view']->filter as $field => $filter) {
            if ($filter->options['exposed']  && $filter->options['id'] == 'field_keywords_tid' ) {
                $field_id = $form['#info']["filter-field_keywords_tid"]['value'];
                asort($form[$field_id]['#options']);
            }
        }
        return $form;
}

function _update_keywords_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['field_keywords_tid'];
}

function _get_associative_array_from_view($viewID, $viewDisplayID, $keyFieldID, $valueFieldID, $contextualFilter){
    $associativeArray = array();
    $associativeArray['All'] = t('- Any -');
    $viewResults = views_get_view_result($viewID, $viewDisplayID, $contextualFilter);
    foreach($viewResults as $viewRow) {
        $associativeArray[$viewRow->$keyFieldID] = $viewRow->$valueFieldID;
    }
    return $associativeArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the second filter dependant in both ways without the need for Views Dependant Filters by adding additional logic to my `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter`.

```
if($form_state['input']['field_commodity_tid'] === 'All')
    $form['field_keywords_tid']['#disabled'] = 1;
}
```

Here is the entire working code:

```
function dependant_keyword_filter_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-annotated-bibliography-page') {

        $form['#after_build'][] = '_sort_alphabetically';

        if(!empty($form_state['values'])) {
            $form_state['input'] = array_merge($form_state['input'], $form_state['values']);
        }

        $selectedCommodity = $form_state['input']['field_commodity_tid'];
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#options'] = _get_associative_array_from_view(
            'annotated_bibliography_dependant_keywords', // view id
            'default', // view display id
            'taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_keywords_tid', // key field id
            'taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_keywords_name',
            $selectedCommodity // term id of the selected shape
            );
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => '_update_keywords_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'keywords_wrapper',
            );
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax']['progress']['type'] = 'throbber';
        $form['field_commodity_tid']['#ajax']['progress']['message'] = 'Updating keywords';
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#prefix'] = '<div id="keywords_wrapper">';
        $form['field_keywords_tid']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

        if($form_state['input']['field_commodity_tid'] === 'All')
            $form['field_keywords_tid']['#disabled'] = 1;
        }
}

function _sort_alphabetically($form, $form_state) {
        foreach ($form_state['view']->filter as $field => $filter) {
            if ($filter->options['exposed']  && $filter->options['id'] == 'field_keywords_tid' ) {
                $field_id = $form['#info']["filter-field_keywords_tid"]['value'];
                asort($form[$field_id]['#options']);
            }
        }
        return $form;
}

function _update_keywords_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['field_keywords_tid'];
}

function _get_associative_array_from_view($viewID, $viewDisplayID, $keyFieldID, $valueFieldID, $contextualFilter){
    $associativeArray = array();
    $associativeArray['All'] = t('- Any -');
    $viewResults = views_get_view_result($viewID, $viewDisplayID, $contextualFilter);
    foreach($viewResults as $viewRow) {
        $associativeArray[$viewRow->$keyFieldID] = $viewRow->$valueFieldID;
    }
    return $associativeArray;
}
```